# Can I modify a package from node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I use `react-redux-snackbar` I want to improved the style into this package, I modify the package from `node_modules` but nothing happens.

When modify `node_modules` into the folder of this plugin, I would like to mmodify the stylesheet but nothing happens.

Do you have any recommandations, like fork the project and create my own plugin ?

Comment: `npm i react-redux-snackbar@<version>` will download the given version, if you just want the latest version, just use `@latest`.

Comment: If I got this right you want to make changes in  react-redux-snackbar locally in your node modules ?

Comment: It's not my question, I would like to custom the CSS into this component and when I update the node_module nothing happen

Comment: @SakhiMansoor Yes you right

Comment: making changes to node_module files is not recommended because when you update the the package using npm update, your changed would reset to initial styles.

Comment: Ok, maybe I fork the project and I created the new version with my improvement ?

Comment: It is not recommended but you can do this for testing if you're saying. make changes and run build script again. Changes will be reflected.

Answer (score 4):

the approach I used for this was to keep a pre-built customised copy in my source tree, and then clobber the module version with it:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cp -r ./src/mycom/lib/tinymce/* ./node_modules/tinymce/",
```

this works after npm -i and in e.g. CI setups. I forked the repo for the lib (tinymce) that i was having trouble with, edited its source, and then built it.

i don't know the npm lib file/folder structure at all really but i copied the ./js folder content into my lib folder and from there into node_modules at install time and it seems to work.

don't forget to tell your linter to ignore your lib folder also e.g.

```
"lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' --ignore-pattern 'src/mycom/lib' --quiet",
"lint:fix": "eslint 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' --ignore-pattern 'src/mycom/lib' --fix --quiet",
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Few options:

- Submit a pull request on the project and wait for the author to
  release it.
- You can fork the project yourself on github and publish it.
- Use a symlink by going to the source folder and using `npm
  link` and then reference it in your project. [Instructions](https://coderwall.com/p/3qhhjw/use-npm-link-to-edit-an-node-js-npm-module-locally).

Comment: `yarn link` also works, that's a great approach

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update package in node_modules, you have to make your changes in project and you rebuild project in node_modules. The rebuild steps are probably in the Readme.md. But if you update project from npm install or other way, probably your project is gonna crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some improvement in some dependency. This is the right time you can make a **Pull Request** to that repo. So it would be available to everyone using the same package. Most importantly if you're working in a team. We don't push `node_modules` in repo. Other members will download packages remotely so your changes will not be reflected there.
I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing you should know, whenever you are making change in node_modules folder, you need to rebuild your project to see its effect,

Now if you have modified node_modules and you restarted your server you will see changes

real issue will occur whenever in future you will try to do `npm i` it will automatically override your changes,

solution to this,

1. Fork project on your GitHub
2. Clone project on your system
3. Create two branches `stable-verison` & `modified-version`
4. Push your desired changes in `modified-version` branch

you will use `stable-verison` branch to sync latest changes from original repo

How you will use this `modified-verion` branch
there 2 ways,

1. Publish your branch as new package on npm
2. Use SHA commit hash to use directly in package.json

here is example for 2nd option
Open up your package.json file, and replace MODULE, USER, REPO, and SHA with the info from the GitHub repo.

```
"MODULE": "https://github.com/USER/REPO/commit/SHA",
```

in your case:

```
"react-redux-snackbar": "https://github.com/yourUser/react-redux-snackbar/commit/Your-Modified-Commit-SHA"
```

i hope this works for you

Answer (score -1):

to update a package you nromally run something like npm install react-redux-snackbar@latest

Comment: Yes Yes, I know that but it's not my question. 
I would like to change the style (CSS), into this package, I change a background for test, but nothing happen

Comment: You should update your question to give a better example of what you are trying to do.